# How to call external code in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am new to Magento. I need to include an external code into my store.

`<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.0.4/dist/aos.js' src_type="url" /></script>`

I have included this above into `app\design\frontend\MMtheme\framework\Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml` but js file makes conflicts.

default_head_blocks.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300" src_type="url" />
    <css src="css/font-awesome.css" />
    <css src="css/grid.css" />
    <css src="css/modules.css" />
    <css src="css/style.css" />
    <css src="css/mega_menu.min.css"/>
    <css src="css/demo.css"/>



<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/mega_menu.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/aos.js"></script>   

</head>
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

You did add the cdn script correctly, however,
Reading the code for aos.js on github, i believe you will need to include it's dependencies and css as well because you are using the rawgit cdn, which may cause issues when dependencies are loaded trough a main file.

I would recommend just downloading the code instead of using a CDN for this.

Could you paste the conflict error?

Comment: Hi Radosav, Thanks for your answer. Conflict means no other js are not working the page contents are messed up.

Comment: I have followed your suggestiona and now an error shows in console. Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (){return function(e){function t(n){if(o[n])return o[n].exports;var i=o[n]={exports:{},id:n,loaded:!1};return e[n].call(i.exports,i,i.exports,t),i.loaded=!0,i.exports}var... ans so on at final http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
 

var e = new Error(msg + '\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#' + id);   in  require.js

Comment: is there anyone to help me?!!!!

Comment: Can you please provide a snippet from default_head_blocks.xml where you include the scripts and a screenshot of the error you got when the conflict arose and after you included the dependencies?

Comment: Radosav, I have edited my question with that xml snippet and added console error screen shot